# Protractor test times out randomly in Docker on Jenkins, works fine in Docker locally

Tags: selenium, docker, jenkins, protractor

When using the APIs defined by Protractor & Jasmine [(the default/supported runner for Protractor)](http://www.protractortest.org/#/frameworks), the tests will always work okay on individual developer laptops. For some reason when the test runs on the Jenkins CI server, they will fail *(despite being in the same docker containers on both hosts, and that was wildly frustrating.)*

1. This error occurs: **A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.**
2. This error also appears: **Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.**

   - Setting `getPageTimeout` & `allScriptsTimeout` to 30 seconds had no effect on this.
   - I tried changing `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` to 60 seconds for all tests in this suite, once the first error appears then every test will wait the full 60 seconds and time out.

I've read and reread [Protractor's page on timeouts](http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts) but none of that seems relevant to this situation.

Even stranger still, it seems like some kind of buffer issue - at first the tests would always fail on a particular spec, and nothing about that spec looked wrong. While debugging I upgraded the selenium docker container from `2.53.1-beryllium` to `3.4.0-einsteinium` and the tests still failed but they failed a couple specs down - suggesting that maybe there was some optimization in the update and so it was able to get more done before it gave out.

I confirmed that by rearranging the order of the specs - the specs that had failed consistently before were now passing and a test that previously passed began to fail (but around the same time in the test duration as the other failures before the reorder.)

**Environment:**

- protractor - `5.1.2`
- selenium/standalone-chrome-debug - `3.4.0-einsteinium`
- docker - `1.12.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being simple - I first found it on [a chrome bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=519952), and it turned out it was also listed right on the front page of the [docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) repo but the text wasn't clear as to what it was for when I'd read it the first time. *(It says that selenium will crash without it, but the errors I was getting from Jasmine were just talking about timeouts, and that was quite misleading.)*

Chrome apparently utilizes `/dev/shm`, and apparently that's fairly small in docker. [There are workarounds for chrome and firefox linked from their README that explain how to resolve the issue.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images)

I had a couple test suites fail after applying the fix but all the test suites have been running and passing for the last day, so I think that was actually the problem and that this solution works. Hope this helps!